# Why doesn't the following, very simple, liquid markup work?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid

```
{% assign base_url = page.url|remove: "index.html" %}
{{ base_url }}
```

Going in, page.url = "/index.html"

Coming out, base_url = "/index.html"

I was hoping base_url would = "/" (without the index.html)

I can type in whatever giberish I like for the filter and I get the same result. If I output directly

```
{{ page.url | remove: "index.html" }}
```

I get the expected "/"

Can filters only be run on direct output and not variables? Please help.

Comment: What Jekyll version are you using? Your example code *(directly copied and pasted from your question)* works for me, on Windows 8.1 and Jekyll 1.5.1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain why the code you posted doesn't work, but I managed to do what you want to do by using the following liquid:

```
{% capture base_url %}{{page.url | replace:'index.html','' }}{%endcapture%}
{{ base_url }}
```

Comment: This is essentially what I wound up doing. It works great (Though it isn't as clean as I would have liked).